# Scanner is scanning full lines with next() and not considering spaces

Tags: java, string, java.util.scanner

I'm trying to put X's and spaces into a 2D array and I keep having problem after problem.  All I want is the text representation to be in 2D array form but when I debug I notice that some cells have full lines in them instead of a string of one character!

If you can visualize the 2D array as a maze, X's being the wall and spaces being the open areas to traverse, then it will help you understand what I am doing.  I just need each cell to have the proper value: an X or a " ".

```
 while(scan.hasNextLine() && r < rows) {
            while(scan.hasNextLine() && c < columns) {
                maze[r][c]=scan.next();
                c++;
            }
            c = 0;
            r++;
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try a slightly different approach:

```
 while(scan.hasNextLine() && r < rows) {
   String line = scan.nextLine();
   char[] characters = line.    toCharArray();
   for (int i=0; i< characters.length; i=i+1{
        maze[r][i] = characters[i];
   }
   r++;
 }
```

Edit: looking at your code, I do not know if it would cause the problem you stated, but your second while loop has 
`scan.hasNextLine()` and since you are actually using `scan.next()` there, it should be `scan.hasNext()`. Also since you are potentially ending the loop early if there are any columns left in the line, maybe it is not going to the next line.

Answer (score 3):

If you're going to use `hasNextLine()` then you'll want to use `nextLine()` to retrieve it. If you don't care about the next line, and really want to deal with the next *token*, then you should be using `hasNext()` and `next()`.

Comment: Please re-read what I said. If you're going to use `hasNextLine()` you should then be using `nextLine()` to get a string. If you don't want the line, then use a different `hasNext*()` method and use the appropriate `next*()` method that goes with it.

Comment: Honestly, I really do not know what you're trying to do. I was just trying to help guide you in the right direction. I suggest you take a step back and rethink how you want to gather your data, and maybe update your question with a better description of what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: added a little extra to my question to help clarify